# Add field to list CSOM Powershell

Tags: powershell, client-object-model

I have written some code which adds a list client side in powershell :

```
   $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)

   $ctx.Credentials = $credentials

   $web = $ctx.Web 

   Invoke-LoadMethod -ClientObject $web

   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

   $ListInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
   $ListInfo.Title = $ListTitle
   $ListInfo.TemplateType = "100"
   $myList = $web.Lists.Add($ListInfo)
   $myList.Description = $ListTitle
   $myList.Update()
   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

What I want to do is create some fields to add to this. Tried this but it didn't work :

```
$myFieldPrivacyStatementurl = $myList.Fields.Add("PrivacyStatementUrls","URL",1)
$myList.Fields[$myFieldPrivacyStatementurl].Title = "Privacy Statement Urls"
$myList.Fields[$myFieldPrivacyStatementurl].Update()
$myFieldIsActive = $myList.Fields.Add("IsActive","Boolean",0)
$myList.Fields[$myFieldIsActive].Title = "Is Active"
$myList.Fields[$myFieldIsActive].Update()
$myFieldSortOrder = $myList.Fields.Add("SortOrder","Number",1)
$myList.Fields[$myFieldSortOrder].Title = "Sort Order"
$myList.Fields[$myFieldSortOrder].Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: YES, this works server side but I want client side

Comment: Get errors when do that piece of code client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs since `Add` method does not accept 3 parameters.

### How to add column into List via CSOM in PowerShell

The following methods are used for adding fields into List:

[FieldCollection.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldcollection.add%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Example: add an existing site column into List

```
#Retrieve List
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Retrieve site columns (fields)
$SiteColumns = $Context.Web.AvailableFields
$Context.Load($SiteColumns)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Find an existing site column
$City =  $Context.Web.AvailableFields | Where {$_.Title -eq "City"}
$Context.Load($City)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Add field to the List
$List.Fields.Add($City)
$List.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

[FieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldcollection.addfieldasxml%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Example: add a new Field into List

```
#Retrieve List
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Add new field to the list
$List.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='Geolocation' DisplayName='Location'/>",$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
$List.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```