# Error in migrating SharePoint 2010 list fields to Office 365 list [CSOM]

Tags: 2010, list, office-365, client-object-model, migration

I am trying to migrate a SharePoint 2010 list to Office 365. I created a new ListCreationInfo for a new list in O365. But when i am to trying add fields from SP2010 list, its giving me an error after list.update()  - 
**A duplicate field name "fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" was found.**

```
              if (!l.Hidden)
                {
                    ListCreationInformation creationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
                    creationInfo.Title = l.Title;
                    creationInfo.TemplateType = l.BaseTemplate; 

                    List list = web.Lists.Add(creationInfo);

                    //Fields in the list
                    ctxOnPrem.Load(l.Fields);
                    ctxOnPrem.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (Field f in l.Fields)
                        list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(f.SchemaXml, true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);

                    list.Update();
                }
```

Note- **l** is the SharePoint 2010 List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code is that AddFieldAsXml() is trying to create new list columns that is the same as existing default SharePoint columns (for example "Title" that has an id = "fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247").

You should first get existing site column (by internal name or GUID) from Web and then add it to the field collection of the list using [Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldcollection.add(v=office.15).aspx) method.

You should also check if the column does not exists in Office 365 site collection, then you should add it using AddFieldAsXml() as you do it now.

Look at the asnwer in this post:

[Add field to list CSOM Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104792/add-field-to-list-csom-powershell)

It is CSOM using PowerShell, but it is similar to C# you're using.