# Programmatically create fields in a SPList using Client Side OM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, content-editor-web-part, csom

Has anyone tried with creating some 20+ `Single line of text SPField` using Client Side OM, like within a Content Editor Web Part.
Because creating a SPList with these many number of columns using SharePoint UI is a tedious job, which is meant for testing purposes only.
I am looking for some kind of code that's doing this, available already.

Answer (score 6):

Since you want to put this into a content editor you'll need to use the JavaScript Client Object Model. Here is something you can use as the source for a content editor that will ask you the list and field title, then let you click a button to create the field, adjust/expand on it as necessary:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.js""></script>
<label for="in_listName">List to create field in:</label>
<input id="in_listName"></input>
<label for="in_fieldName">Enter a name for your new field:</label>
<input id="in_fieldName"></input>
<button id="btn_createField" type="button">Create Field</button>

<script>
    function createColumns_click(listTitle, fieldTitle) {
        var myCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var myList = myCtx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var newField = myList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml("<Field DisplayName=\'" + fieldTitle + "\' Type=\'Text\' />", true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        newField.update();
        myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            alert("Field <" + fieldTitle + "> created!");
        }, function(sender, args){
            alert("Error:\n" + args.get_message());
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        $("#btn_createField").click(function() {
            var listName = $("#in_listName").val();
            var fieldName = $("#in_fieldName").val();
            createColumns_click(listName, fieldName);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you're already using jQuery you can omit the script tag at the top.

I don't actually like using the `fields.addFieldAsXml` function, I wish it was easier to create an `SP.FieldText` (or any other type) object, but trying to create the object directly on the list like other `ClientObjects` gives me a constructor error; I haven't found any good examples on how to create new `SP.FieldText` objects directly.

---

**Edit:**

Here is how you could use a semi-colon seperated list as one of the inputs so that you could create multiple fields at the same time:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.js""></script>
<div>
    <label for="in_listName">List to create field in:</label>
    <input id="in_listName"></input>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="in_fieldName">Enter a semi-colon seperated list of field titles:</label>
    <input id="in_fieldName"></input>
</div>
<button id="btn_createField" type="button">Create Field</button>

<script>    
function createColumnsArr_click(listTitle, fieldTitles) {
    var myCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var myList = myCtx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    $.each(fieldTitles, function (idx, item) {
        var newField = myList.get_fields()
            .addFieldAsXml(
            "<Field DisplayName=\'" + item + "\' Type=\'Text\' />",
            true,
            SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue
            );
        newField.update();
    });
    myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        alert("Created fields:/n" + fieldTitles.toString());
    }, function (sender, args) {
        alert("Error:\n" + args.get_message());
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("#btn_createField").click(function () {
        var listName = $("#in_listName").val();
        var fieldName = $("#in_fieldName").val().split(";");
        createColumnsArr_click(listName, fieldName);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: But he wants to do all this in one go and not one by one. This is similar to doing it the UI way.

Comment: @Akhoy It saves a number of clicks, scrolling, and form entry per field. Additionally, you could easily modify it to take an array of fieldTitles and loop through the new field creation section (`var newField ...; newField.update();`) before calling `myCtx.executeQueryAsync`. Plus it uses the client object model, and it can be used inside of a content editor, as specified in the OP's question.

Comment: Right. This is better than the previous answer then. Needs only 1 POST compared to 20+ POSTs. I think you should also include the array part since i think that is what the OP wants. +1

Comment: @akhoy - updated

Comment: This one is better that me. Should be accepted +1

Answer (score 3):

Did not try yet but know the trick using REST API. You have to send 20+ POST requests to the following `URL`

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'Guid Id of your list')/fields
```

Request body will be

```
var data = {
    '__metadata': {
        'type': 'SP.FieldText'
    },
    'FieldTypeKind': 2,
    'Title': 'Project Name',
    'MaxLength': '22'
};
```

**Update based on comment.** Write a function like following

```
    function addField(fieldName) {

    var data = {
        '__metadata': {
            'type': 'SP.FieldText'
        },
        'FieldTypeKind': 2,
        'Title': fieldName,
        'MaxLength': '22'
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Your List Name')/Fields",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Now execute the function 20+ times by providing your `fieldName` parameter.

**NB:** Change the List name in `url`

But you should use PowerShell for creating multiple columns. See [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/104802/21421)

```
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

# Add new field to the list
$List.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='Text' DisplayName='Location'/>", $true, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
$List.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: comment will be appreciated in case down vote

Comment: tip: Use [Chrome Snippets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470711/chrome-developer-tools-what-is-snippets-support) to built a collection of *snippets* in your (SharePoint) Toolbelt. (ps. downvote was not me)

Comment: It's ok but I did not get the actual problem of my current code snippets

Comment: Am not aware of REST API.I need to look into this, how to use this.Thanks for the info and  sample.

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: Also add a Title parameter to the function, as now each field will get a "YOUR Field Title" as *DisplayName* but sequentional numbering added as *Internalname*

Comment: @SaMolPPp follow what Danny has said

Comment: Am I making sense now @DannyEngelman boss?